# Downloading Z specification for mac

Tags: formal-languages, z-notation

sorry if this doesn't belong in overflow but I have a real urge to continue making specifications using Z, as I've come to learn it during uni this year.

I wanted to know if its possible to download it on a mac pc, as I currently understand its normally used on Linux or SunOS but I don't have either at home. I would greatly appreciate the resources to where I can download it as I couldn't find any by googling it. I'm wanting to install zans animator and ztc type checker as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question was asked a year ago, here is a link on how you can do it:
http://andrius.velykis.lt/2012/09/installing-zeves-on-mac-os-x/

Other people might be interested in this.

Comment: thanks man, i can finally keep myself in the know about this kickass schema language